# Google Analytics, Ionic app - unusual tracking data

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I am in the process of building an app with Ionic (for Android and iOS). I am using this plugin: https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.

I have built the app and installed it on my Android development device (and iOS emulator) and know where else. I am based in Sydney, Australia and this should be the only location tracked. However when I view the GA dashboard I an told the app has been viewed from Russia on a Linux i686 device.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Just to clear-up that this is an App not a website

Comment: what are the co-ordinates (lat/long) for the Russia location shown on the GA dashborad?

Comment: I can't find the exact co-ordinates but Moscow and Samara are the two locations showing up . I also looked as Acquisition > Sources and found the following two sources:   

forum.topic56710991.darodar.com / referral      

 ilovevitaly.com / referral

I guess I am a little confused as to how anybody could be viewing the app or linking to it when it hasn't been released anywhere, nor has any of the code?